# How can I make a TLS connection using Vala?

Tags: glib, vala, gio

I'm trying to figure out how can I make a proper TLS connection using Gio. The Gio documentation says you can create a TLS connection just by setting the `tls` flag on the `SocketClient`. Below is a Gio networking sample from the gnome wiki. When I set the `tls` flag, the TLS layer is configured automatically but validating the certificates fails unless I skip the validation.

Do I have to validate certificates myself or is `GLib` supposed to do the validation? Can somebody provide a full example on how to use TLS in Vala?

```cs
var host = "developer.gnome.org";

try {
    // Resolve hostname to IP address
    var resolver = Resolver.get_default ();
    var addresses = resolver.lookup_by_name (host, null);
    var address = addresses.nth_data (0);
    print (@"Resolved $host to $address\n");

    // Connect
    var client = new SocketClient ();
    client.set_tls(true);
    // skips certificate validation
    client.set_tls_validation_flags( 0 );

    var conn = client.connect (new InetSocketAddress (address, 443));
    print (@"Connected to $host\n");

    // Send HTTP GET request
    var message = @"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
    conn.output_stream.write (message.data);
    print ("Wrote request\n");

    // Receive response
    var response = new DataInputStream (conn.input_stream);
    var status_line = response.read_line (null).strip ();
    print ("Received status line: %s\n", status_line);

} catch (Error e) {
    stderr.printf ("%s\n", e.message);
}
```

And another thing I want to ask is; when I run the code above I get this output:

```
Resolved developer.gnome.org to 8.43.85.14
Connected to developer.gnome.org
Wrote request
Received status line: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But when I try to connect *'developer.mozilla.org'*, I'm getting the following error:

```
Resolved developer.mozilla.org to 54.192.235.2
Error performing TLS handshake: A packet with illegal or unsupported version was received.
```

Can anybody tell me the reason why I am getting this error? *(By the way the version of GLib installed on my system is 2.64.6)*

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing so far is mostly correct, but you will probably want to do a little bit more to handle potential certificate errors during the TLS handshaking (see below).

> Do I have to validate certificates myself or is GLib supposed to do the validation?

Note that [`SocketClient.set_tls_validation_flags`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.SocketClient.set_tls_validation_flags.html) is deprecated. To handle validation errors you can connect to the [`accept_certificate`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.TlsConnection.accept_certificate.html) signal on the `TlsClientConnection` prior to handshaking:

```
var client = new SocketClient ();
client.set_tls(true);
client.event.connect ((SocketClientEvent event, SocketConnectable connectable, IOStream? connection) => {
    if (event == SocketClientEvent.TLS_HANDSHAKING) {
        ((TlsClientConnection) connection).accept_certificate.connect ((peer_cert, errors) => {
            // Return true to accept, false to reject
        });
    }
});
```

The `errors` are [`GLib.TlsCertificateFlags`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.TlsCertificateFlags.html), so you'll want to determine which (if any) are acceptable. Ideally if there are any errors you would reject the certificate altogether, but if you want to allow self-signed certificates for example, that is possible this way.

You can simply check against the flags to see which ones are included in the `errors`:

```
TlsCertificateFlags[] flags = new TlsCertificateFlags[] {
    TlsCertificateFlags.BAD_IDENTITY,
    TlsCertificateFlags.EXPIRED,
    TlsCertificateFlags.GENERIC_ERROR,
    TlsCertificateFlags.INSECURE,
    TlsCertificateFlags.NOT_ACTIVATED,
    TlsCertificateFlags.REVOKED,
    TlsCertificateFlags.UNKNOWN_CA
};
foreach (var flag in flags) {
    if ((errors & flag) != 0) {
        // The flag was included in the errors - respond accordingly
    }
}
```

---

> But when I try to connect 'developer.mozilla.org', I'm getting the
> following error:
>
> Resolved developer.mozilla.org to 54.192.235.2 Error performing TLS
> handshake: A packet with illegal or unsupported version was received.
>
> Can anybody tell me the reason why I am getting this error? (By the
> way the version of GLib installed on my system is 2.64.6)

This is probably due to `developer.mozilla.org` using an old implementation of TLS (probably 1.0 or 1.1). These were disabled in GLib networking as of 2.64.x according to this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954742

They may have upgraded to TLS 1.2 since you posted this question - I just did a quick test and connected using TLSv1.2 successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try run the program with `export G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all` for full debug messages.

Also, for a full working example of code that uses TLS written in Vala via GIO, check out the code for this Gemini browser: https://github.com/koyuspace/fossil/blob/main/src/util/connection_helper.vala

I hope that this is somewhat useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the link. I'll check that out as soon as possible.